I'm struggling to get a .csv file from a Git-hub post using python
I'm trying to get a .csv file from this git post: link.
So far i tried screaping with:
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
url = 'https://github.com/hiring-lab/job_postings_tracker/blob/master/US/aggregate_job_postings_US.csv'
response = requests.request("GET", url)
soup = bs4(response.content, "html.parser")

But could not find the table inside the soup.
I also findout that i could simply use:
link = 'https://github.com/hiring-lab/job_postings_tracker/blob/master/US/aggregate_job_postings_US.csv'
dados = pd.read_csv(link, sep=',', index_col='date')

But also didn't work. Output: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 40, saw 25

As per the suggested duplicate, on the page, click on the "Raw" field (to the right on the page) and use that url. In this case: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hiring-lab/job_postings_tracker/master/US/aggregate_job_postings_US.csv". Using pd.read_csv should work just fine on that.

I tought i tried that, my bad! Thank u any way

use Raw method
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hiring-lab/job_postings_tracker/master/US/aggregate_job_postings_US.csv'

try:
    data = pd.read_csv(url, sep=',', index_col='date')
    print(data.head()) 
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

Output
           jobcountry  ...        variable
date                   ...                
2020-02-01         US  ...  total postings
2020-02-02         US  ...  total postings
2020-02-03         US  ...  total postings
2020-02-04         US  ...  total postings
2020-02-05         US  ...  total postings

[5 rows x 4 columns]

